# Is there a way to add code on a function from another Class without inheritance?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a class that has a function foo() that counts to 3 and we want from another class to be able to modify this function and after modifying it counts to 3 that was previously declared but also executes the new code too. The function foo() would only be called by class1 and i dont want to use inheritance. The new code that im supposed to add lets say it doesnt have any relationship with class1.

For Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class class1 {
public:
    class1()
    {
        
    }
    void foo()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<2;i++)
        {cout << i << endl;}
    }
};

class class2 {
public:
    class2()
    {
       
    }
    void foo() override
    {
       Super::foo();
       cout << "Jump from a cliff" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{   
    class1 c1 = class1();
    class2 c2 = class2();
    c1.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
Jump From a cliff
```

Comment: It is not possible to add code on a function from another Class even with inheritance.

Comment: Your design is flawed. Either `class1` and `class2` have a relation or they haven't. (You must make a decision for either/or.) If `class2` has an effect on the internal state of `class1`, `class2` should have a pointer or reference to `class1`, and `class1` should have an internal state (e.g. an `int` member variable) which can be modified from outside. (In extrem cases, it might be `protected` or `private` with `class2` a `friend`.)

Comment: "doesnt have any relationship with class1." - No. You need at least an asssociation, like in a decorator pattern.

Comment: Are you looking for [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat What if class2 has a pointer then?

Comment: "What if class2 has a pointer then?" - Then that's a relationship

Comment: Think it like I want to create a dynamic Interface which is not...

Answer (score 0):

You need an object to call a non-static member function.

If you want to get desired output from `class2::foo` you can implement it for example like this:

```
class class2 {
public:
    void foo() 
    {
       class1 x;
       x.foo();
       cout << "Jump from a cliff" << endl;
    }

};
```

Alternatively `class1` can have a member of type `class1`.

Comment: No It won't do. Think foo() function is like a broadcast, which before broadcasting i want to modify it to broadcast something else too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on Array of function pointers.

Comment: Now, it seems to me you was looking for something like a [Signal-Slot concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots) (also known as [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yes, i was looking something like that. But I implemented my solution using an array of function pointers to pass the extra functionality.